# Display string in grid with datetime as filter option

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to show datetime in grids but when i used string the filter is getting applied but it is in string(contains,end with..).How to display string datecolumn field in grids with datetime as filter option in blazor?

Comment: Show the code that puts the data into the grid. I'm expecting to see Blazor markup containing the grid, a code section with some sample data in it and some variables you've wired up. If you want to go the whole hog and paste it into something that lets us fiddle with it, like https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet (a website that allows one to mess with a library for Blazor called MudBlazor, but also accepts normal blazor stuff) or similar thats a bonus

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.